# WAMPServer 2.5 installed without first installing MSVCR110 runtime

Tags: runtime-error, wamp, wampserver

I've Installed Wamp. But When I Open It, shows a error:

'The Program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.'
I've also reinstalled but It doesn't worked.
What is the Solution to this Problem?

Comment: You need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db?auth=1).

Comment: I have installled already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed WAMPServer 2.5 without first installing the MSVC11 runtime then the Apache service will not have been registered. To register the Apache service do this

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service

(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start Resume Service
```

Apache should now be installed as a service and running i.e. the wampmanager icon should go Green.